# Blazor Server Side Data Annotation - [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(###)-###-####}")] Not working

Tags: blazor

I may be down the wrong rabbit hole here, but used this in MVC, is this not possible in Blazor?

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(###)-###-####}")]
    public string HomeTelephone { get; set; }
```

Comment: And how/where do you Display that HomeTelephone ?